# Using BeautifulSoup in order to extract <ul><li> elements and contain store it structure

Tags: beautifulsoup, html-lists

Recently, I'm working on problem about how to extract the structure. But I don't how to solve it.
I have a html **scraped** like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><object type="text/sitemap"><param name="Name" value="level1"/)</object>
    <ul>
        <li><object type="text/sitemap"><param name="Name" value="data1"/></object></li>
        <li><object type="text/sitemap"><param name="Name" value="level2"/></object>
        <ul>
            <li><object type="text/sitemap"><param name="Name" value="data2"/></object></li>    
            <li><object type="text/sitemap"><param name="Name" value="data3"/></object></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

I want to get the desired output like this:

```
output = [level1 --- data1, level1 --- level2 ----data2, level1 ---- level2 ----data3]
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your HTML tag is missing . After I add it, the running result using simplifieddoc is as follows

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc
html='''
<ul>
    <li><object type="text/sitemap"><param name="Name" value="level1"/></object>
    <ul>
        <li><object type="text/sitemap"><param name="Name" value="data1"/></object></li>
        <li><object type="text/sitemap"><param name="Name" value="level2"/></object>
        <ul>
            <li><object type="text/sitemap"><param name="Name" value="data2"/></object></li>    
            <li><object type="text/sitemap"><param name="Name" value="data3"/></object></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</ul>'''
def test(ul,l_name,lst):
  l1s = ul.children
  l1_len=len(l1s)
  for i in range(0,l1_len-1): # level1
    l1 = l1s[i]
    l1n = l1s[i+1]
    if l1.tag=='li':
      if l1n.tag=='ul':
        l_name = l_name+'-'+l1.param.value if l_name else l1.param.value
        test(l1n,l_name,lst)
      else:
        lst.append(l_name+'-'+l1.param.value)
    if i==l1_len-2:
      if l1n.tag=='li':
        lst.append(l_name+'-'+l1n.param.value)
doc = SimplifiedDoc()
doc.loadHtml(doc.replaceReg(html,'</object>[\s]*<ul','</object></li><ul'))
ul = doc.ul
lst = []
test(ul,'',lst)
print (lst)
```

Result:

```
['level1-data1', 'level1-level2-data2', 'level1-level2-data3']
```

You can get the examples of SimplifiedDoc [here](https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples)